# Using richfaces 3.3.3 with portlets(JSF 1.2 ) on IBM Websphere Portal 6.1 server

Tags: jsf, richfaces, portlet, websphere-portal

I am trying to use richfaces 3.3.3 multiple fileupload functionality. I was successfull using it in JSF1.2 with apache tomcat server, but not able to implement it in portlets( in IBM WebSphere portal 6.1 server).

I have the following jars added apart from the regular jsf jars in lib:=
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar, commons-collections-3.2.jar, commons-digester-1.8.jar, commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, jhighlight-1.0.jar, richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar, richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar, richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar, richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar.

Following were added(extra) in web.xml:-

```
    <context-param>

   <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>

   <param-value>blueSky</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->

<context-param>

      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>

      <param-value>enable</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->

<filter> 

   <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 

<init-param>  
<param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>  
<param-value>false</param-value>  
</init-param> 

</filter> 



<filter-mapping> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>
```

Rest all were as usual . With this i was able to use it without any problem on Tomcat.

But these configuration fails when I try to implement it in portlets.
Googling and reading other blogs suggested that there is problem with the portletbridge and I should be using jboss-portletbridge.Tried various combinations as suggested by many. getting different errors each time.

Can anyone help me on this. Any insight is appreciated...

Comment: Anyother api for multiple file uploads like richfaces?

Answer (score 0):

JSF 1.2 is available on Portal 6.1 only if you installed Portal on WebSphere Application Server 7.x. That is highly unrecommendable, because using that configuration your environment does not have any vendor supported upgrade path. Migrations from 6.1+7.x combination are not supported by IBM. You'd better off changing the framework you are using to something that will not cause such problems for you.